# find max logons in an interval

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with `timestamps` and `states` for people.

```
|:--------------------------------------------------------------:|
| user_id   |  state | start_time          | end_time            |
|:--------------------------------------------------------------:|
| 4711      |  1     | 2013-10-30 09:01:23 | 2013-10-30 17:12:03 |
| 4712      |  1     | 2013-10-30 07:01:23 | 2013-10-30 18:12:03 |
| 4713      |  1     | 2013-10-30 08:01:23 | 2013-10-30 16:12:03 |
| 4714      |  1     | 2013-10-30 09:01:24 | 2013-10-30 17:02:03 |
```

My challenge is, to find out how many users are 
`MAX(logged on) AND AVG(logged on)` in same time per Interval. I think that I get out when I can see, how many users are simultaneously logged in per second.

```
|:-------------------------------------:|
| timestamp  |  state | userid          |
|:-------------------------------------:|
| 1383123683 |  1     | 4711            |
| 1383123684 |  1     | 4711            |
| 1383123684 |  1     | 4712            |
| 1383123685 |  1     | 4711            |
| 1383123685 |  1     | 4712            |
| ...        | ...    | ...             |
```

By the way, one intervals is a quarter of an hour.

The Data comes via `INSERT INTO` so my idea was to crate a trigger and wrote in a helper table one row for each second (UNIX timestamp) between start and end adding the `state_id`.

At the end, it must be possible to group over the seconds and count over the `datasets` to find out, how many rows are exist in one second. For the `AVG` I have not yet a formula :-). It's a question of time, you know.

But I'm not sure, if my idea was a good one, because i fear that my plan needs a lot of performance and space.

The better idea will be, to wrote just the `start-time` and `end-time`, but i loosing the possibility to grouping over the seconds.

How I can manage that without thousands of rows in my database?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand phrase _By the way, one intervals is a quarter of an hour_ do you mean that start_time and end_time always ends with `:0:0` `:15:0` `:30:0` `45:0` ? Another question - is there possibility for user to have overlapped loggedin times?

Comment: The interval is just an info. the max value should be calculated for an interval. I think this information is not so important for the solution. Yes, users can have overlapping login_times, as my example shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here can be several solutions, I want to describe one, and I hope you can use/adapt/extent it for your particular needs (NOTE: I'm using mysql dialect, for ms sql it can be a little bit different syntax, but approach will work):

**1** create new table, with structure like:

```
create table changelog (
changetime datetime,
changevalue int,
totalsum int,
primary key (changetime)
);
```

**2** insert basic data:

```
insert into changelog
select changet, sum(cnts), 0
from
(
select start_time as changet, 1 as cnts from testlog
union all
select end_time as changet, -1 from testlog
) as q
group by changet;
```

**3** update totalsum colum:

```
update changelog as a set totalsum = ifnull((select sum(changevalue) from (select changet, sum(cnts) as changevalue, 0
from
(
select start_time as changet, 1 as cnts from testlog
union all
select end_time as changet, -1 from testlog
) as q
group by changet) as b where b.changet<=a.changetime),0);
```

NOTE: for ms sql you can try `with` syntax, you will be able to do these insert/update as one query

**4** after this you will have (based on data from question):

```
2013-10-30 07:01:23 1   1
2013-10-30 08:01:23 1   2
2013-10-30 09:01:23 1   3
2013-10-30 09:01:24 1   4
2013-10-30 16:12:03 -1  3
2013-10-30 17:02:03 -1  2
2013-10-30 17:12:03 -1  1
2013-10-30 18:12:03 -1  0
```

As you see, max logged in already here, but here is one problem, imagine that you need to select data for range: 08:00-08:01, there are no data in table, so query like this will not work:

```
SELECT max(totalsum)
FROM changelog
where changetime between cast(@startrange as datetime) and cast(@endrange as datetime)
```

but you can change it to:

```
SELECT max(totalsum)
from
(
select max(totalsum) as totalsum FROM changelog
where changetime between cast(@startrange as datetime) and cast(@endrange as datetime)
union all
select totalsum from changelog where changetime=(select max(changetime) from changelog where changetime<cast(@startrange as datetime))
) as q;
```

so, basically saying - in addition to your range you need to fetch last row before period starts, to find out how many users was at the moment of range start

**5** now, you want to calculate average. Average is kinda tricky function, depending on what you understand - there can be different results, average user's per second or average workload

here is the difference:

```
100 users logged in at 09:00
98 users logged out at 09:01
1 user logged out at 09:02
Selection range: 09:00 - 09:59 (inclusive)
```

average per minute will be sum of all logged in users in each minute and divided by 60

```
(100 + 2 + 1 + 57*1)/60 = 2.6(6) user per minute
```

but average workload can be calculated as (max(logged_users)+min(logged_users)) / 2

```
(100 + 1)/2 = 50.5 users, this is average simultaneous users logged in system
```

another average can be calculated via SQL avg (sum(values)/count(values)), which will give us

```
(100+98+1)/3 = 66.3(3) - another average workload in persons
```

first formula says to us that it *only* 2.65 user at the same time, but second shows "holy #*&#@#@, it is 50.5 users at the same time"

**another example:**

```
100 users logged in at 09:00
99 users logged out at 09:58
1 user logged out at 09:59
Selection range: 09:00 - 09:59 (inclusive)
```

first formula will give you `(100*58 + 2 + 1)/60 = 96.71(6)` users, second will continue to give `50.5`, 3rd one still `66.3(3)`

what average suits best for you?

To calculate 1st average you need to create `stored procedure` which will get data for each minute/seconds of period and summarize it, after divide

To calculate 2nd variant: just select `min/max` and divide by 2

3rd variant: use `avg` instead of max

Note #1: of course all this approaches are quite slow with huge traffic, so I suggest you to prepare some "pre-calculated" tables with data which can be fetched fast (for example you can have data for each hour like: `YYYY-MM-DD HH loggedInatStart, min, avg, median, max, loggedInatEnd`)

Note #2: sometimes [median average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) is more interesting for statistical purposes, to obtain it you will: for each minute calculate how many users was logged in, select distinct values, select middle from this list (for my examples this will give us 2 and 2), or select all values, select middle one (for my example it will give us 1 and 99)

Comment: thank you so much for your great code and the lot of lines. it works as a sample and i test it in mssql environment on my productive data. i will post a comment after the test.

Comment: hi ilya, i try hard to update my table in mssql with the command ;with. but i fail. i get one dataset via trigger in the inserted pseudo table. could you please be so extreamly kindly to give me q clue, how to calculate the totalsum in a trigger? Thanks

Comment: @Frank in trigger you need only to fetch previous row `select top 1 totalsum from tbl order by id desc` and then inc or dec it by 1

Comment: hi ilya, thank you for your fast answer. Setting a variable in trigger results an error, cause returned more than 1 value. i assume this is the wrong way. can you help me with the ;with as an alternative. Thanks in advanced - Frank

Comment: @Frank it is impossible, check select TOP 1 - only 1 value can be returned

Comment: you are really very fast man. i had two other paramters, because i won't just watching on logon. There are 5 different states and some reasons. So i have to set more than 1 var in trigger and a where filter in my query. That throws the error. This is the reason i assume that this is the wrong way.

Comment: @Frank it is very hard to answer such broad question, if you have error with multiple rows returned - then return only 1 or re-check your whole logic

Comment: do you have an idea, how i can manage step 2 and 3 in one MYSQL-Query. The raw-data are stored in mysql, so probably it will be more performant do did these things on the source-side. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Frank instead of 0 value in 2nd query, put 3rd query